# How to prevent changing size of material-ui Checkbox component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am building a React app, where changing **global font-size** is implemented. That's pretty easy when using the material, since there is  wrapper which receives `theme` object.
theme object is created with a call to `createMuiTheme()` which is also provided by the material. The object from mobx store is massed to  `createMuiTheme()`.
Everything works smoothly, but **there are certain components, which I want to be immune to font size changes**.

Although I managed to set custom JSS styles for several of them, there is one, which seems to be immune to everything when it comes to hardcoding the size - every time I change the global font-size, those goddamn material UI checkboxes also change size. I tried jss, inline styles, classes, className...

here is the code of the Checkbox (Checkbox is also from material-ui)
BTW material ui version is    "@material-ui/core": "^4.7.2",

```
          <FormControl className={classes.badgeContainer}>
                <Badge
                    badgeContent={severity.value}
                    classes={{badge: classes[severity.category]}}
                    showZero={true}
                >

                    <ConfiguredTooltip
                        textInTooltip={severity.category}
                    >
                        <Checkbox
                            checked={severity.checked}
                            onChange={this.handleChange(severity.category)}
                            value={severity.category}
                            color={"default"}
                            disabled={!!currentlyActiveScheme && !schemeEditedFlag}
                            classes={{root: classes.checkbox}}
                        />
                    </ConfiguredTooltip>
                </Badge>
            </FormControl>
```

All those components are form material-ui

Comment: did you try adding `!important` to the font-size declaration?

Comment: damn, forgot about that. Thats good, gonna check if it works, wait a minute...

Comment: nah, doesn't work. It was good try, though.

Comment: Bummer. Use a [nested theme](https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/#nesting-the-theme) to wrap your Checkbox maybe?

Comment: Thats another idea. Lets try that

Comment: Yes, it worked, that You, @hotpink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to sum up, thanks to hotpink, all Checkboxes or Checkboxes groups have to be wrapped in separate `MuiThemeProvider`.
I created one separate const named `themeForCheckboxes` (:P) for all Checkboxes, placed it in mobx store responsible for layout stuff and *voila*, it works.
Kinda sad, that we have to do it in such a way, but for now there is no better solution.
Doable, and fast.